# Getting raspbian repositories on Kali Linux on Zero

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, kali, repository

I have been working with the Kali Linux distribution built for the Raspberry Pi Zero, and am running into a bit of a problem.  It is running fine, but I am having trouble installing Raspbian packages on it.  Specifically, I want to be able to access the Raspi Camera.

Here is my current sources.list:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

But when I run apt-get update, this error is generated:

```
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armel/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armel'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-armel/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armel'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-armel/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armel'
root@kali:~#
```

I can still install any packages in the Kali repository fine, but when I try to install raspistill, apt-get says that it can't find the package raspistill.

What am I doing wrong?  I have seen something online about Raspbian not supporting armel, (which is what the Zero runs), but is that true?  If so, how do I get Raspbian repositories on the Raspberry Pi Zero?

As a secondary question, if anyone knows a way to access the RasPi Cam on a different distribution than Raspbian, please let me know.  I have done extensive research and have not been able to get anything to work.

Comment: *"As a secondary question"* -> [How can I install raspistill/raspicam on a distro that doesn't include them?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67156/5538)

Comment: Yup, that takes care of the secondary question.  Thanks!  Now I just need to figure out why I can't get Raspbian packages in Kali.

Comment: The Zero supports Raspbian armhf. The Zero will never run Debian armhf.

Answer (score 1):

Wheezy ("Old-Stable") is no longer the *current* distribution of Raspbian (and Debian from which it is derived) but not being familiar with Kali I am not sure from what it derives it's parentage - what do they say you should have in your `sources.list` ***currently*** - beware of using old documentation...!

Mixing repository sources is not a good idea *unless* a derivative distribution says it is OK to - they might suggest the "parent" from which they derived their own versions from - but only for the things they do not provide themselves, otherwise things can get broken quickly...

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called katoolin. You can use that software. The script is written in python. Just opne the software from terminal with

```
sudo python katoolin.py
```

and you will find options for everything

[Katoolin](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin)

Comment: I know Katoolin is for Ubunto 18.  Is it OK with Rpi4 buster?

Comment: Yes it is.. Same thing..You have to run it with python command. Select the answer if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice.  I am a huge fan of python but C++ hater! :).  I do use C Sharp, but it is poorly supported in Rpi4B buster. :(

Comment: @tlfong01 c sharp has nothing to do with using katoolin. That is another thing